# UITableView Gray out every cell except for the selected cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I'm trying to mimic the functionality seen in the Voice Memo and Voice Mail Tables on the iPhone. When a cell is selected, all the other cells are grayed out and disabled.

![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2tXB.png "Example"

My thought was to run a loop in the "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" method and disable each cell that wasn't the selected IndexPath. But that seem inefficient. Is there another way?

Comment: Should the user be able to scroll the table view while an item is selected and all the other items are disabled?

Comment: Make your background color gray and your selection color white.

Comment: @Logan: I should have clarified. The initial state is that all cells are white. When one is selected, they rest go gray. If the selected cell is pressed it will deselect and go back to white.

Comment: @DanielT. No, the user should not be able to scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the user should not be able to scroll. I would create two black/alpha UIViews and place one above the selected cell and one below the selected cell. I would either have these two views intercept any taps, or disable user interaction for the underlying tableView, whichever is easiest.

Comment: That's a clever approach. If you were doing this with two sections, would you need 3 black/alpha UIViews?

Comment: Yes, and keep in mind that all but one of them could have a height of zero.